# Issues Regarding Rest Api

Tags: magento-2.1, rest-api

I made a website in Angular, Node.JS. But backend is using Magento 2.1.12. How to make a secure website by calling admin token, customer token generated. This Angular frontend call rest API for products, it needs admin token. But if I give admin token, it creates security issues.

Comment: Do you want to generate secure admin and customer token using REST right ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Oauth credentials. Security issues wont come